# jQuery function in .click() etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So normally, I do it like this:

```
$('#selectRoom a').click( function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); // To prevent the default behavior (following the link or adding # to URL)
// Do some function specific logic here
});
```

However, I would like to do it like this, to clean things up (and be able to reuse):

```
$('#selectRoom a').click( selectRoom );

function selectRoom () {
    e.preventDefault(); // To prevent the default behavior (following the link or adding # to URL)
    // Do some function specific logic here
}
```

The problem is, i cant pass the "e" event-handler to the function, then the selectRoom() function is called on load. i.e:

```
$('#selectRoom a').click( selectRoom(e) );
```

Can I fix this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it like this:

```
function selectRoom(e) {
  // now e will work
}
```

Do **not** do this:

```
$('#selectRoom a').click(selectRoom(e)); // WRONG DO NOT DO THIS
```

because that means, "Call the function selectRoom and then pass its return value to the "click" function in jQuery."  You want to pass jQuery the *name* of the funcion, not the result of executing the function. Thus:

```
$('#selectRoom a').click(selectRoom);
```

Answer (score 6):

selectRoom() will be given the event:

`function selectRoom(e)`

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return false from the function to prevent the event from continue to bubble.